# Saving python files from VSCode - saving as source file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I currently have a large chunk of python code that was written in VScode and saved as a .py file. When I go to my windows file explorer and look at where it was saved, it says it saved as a 'windows source file' rather than a 'python file'

I am trying to create a windows task that automates this script in python and I think, because it is being saved as a source file, it isn't running the script.

If anyone knows how to save my python script from VScode as a python file rather than a python source file, i would really appreciate it. Any other tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

Image of .py file saved as source file:

[image]

Adding .py source file to windows task scheduler:

[image]

Result of task scheduler when using the source file:

[image]

Comment: I think if you open this file in text editor and you should show your code. Problem can make only file extension which Windows uses to recognize file type. But data in file doesn't have to match to extension.

Comment: maybe first in file explorer  turn on option to show file extensions.

Comment: I don't use Window but maybe it need to set task as `python.exe your_script.py`

Answer (score 1):

What ended up working for me was placing my python exe location and .py file location into a txt file and saving it as batch file (.bat). I upload the batch file where it says program/script.

[image: Batch]

Comment: hi @JialeDu, it will not let me click the check mark on my own answer